# I kind of change the nautilus and window theme

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes

Some days ago I worked on changing the theme of my Ubuntu 14.10. 
But I can't remember what I did in detail :P 
Since a few days my Nautilus looks like I'm using gnome. Can somebody tell me how to get the normal nautilus and window theme back?
 Thanks very much.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR1bd.png

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in a terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Ambiance"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Ambiance"
```

Comment: thanks for your help but after these commands I still have the same title bar like in the pic i posted